# Is it possible to annotate an Arara script with comments?

Tags: comments, arara

Is it possible to embed comments inside an Arara script, i.e. inside the sequence of Arara directives that goes inside the `.tex` file to guide the compilation?

For instance, consider the following document.

```
% arara: halt
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to add a comment to the first line, say

```
% arara: halt # Arara will halt unconditionally.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can make the comments in separate lines:

```
% explaining why pdflatex needs to run
% arara: pdflatex
%
% explaining next step
% arara: pdflatex
```

This may not be perfect, but at least the information is very near to the arara directive if refers to.

(only make sure that all lines are commented with %, otherwise tex will complain)